# Start CSS animation with on set of key frames then then loop another set of keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get an object to lead in with one CSS animation key frame set and then have it loop another key frame set forever. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are willing to do for it :)

I don't think that there is a solution to trigger the second animation from within the last keyframe of the first animation.

A possible solution would be to delay the second animation until the first one has finished like this:

```css
#test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: grey;
  animation: 2s firstAnimation forwards, 1s secondAnimation 2s alternate infinite;
  /* the "2s" after "secondAnimation" is for the delay */
}

@keyframes firstAnimation {
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
}

@keyframes secondAnimation {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Another possible approach is to verify with javascripts `onanimationend` and then add the second animation by adding a class for example:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test")
test.onanimationend = function(event) {
  console.log(event) // contains a lot of interesting infos like the name of the animation that ended :)
  test.classList.remove("startFirstAnimation")
  test.classList.add("startSecondAnimation")
}
```

```css
#test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.startFirstAnimation {
  animation: 2s firstAnimation forwards;
}

@keyframes firstAnimation {
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
}

.startSecondAnimation {
  width: 100px !important; /* cheating a little bit here to keep the state of the end of the firstAnimation... */
  background: red !important;
  animation: 1s secondAnimation alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes secondAnimation {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="startFirstAnimation"></div>
```